# Rescale pandas column based on a value within that column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to normalize a column of data to 1 based on an internal standard control across several batches of data.  However, I'm struggling to do this natively in pandas and not splitting things into multiple chunks with for loops.

```
import pandas as pd

Test_Data = {"Sample":["Control","Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4","Control","Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4"],
           "Batch":["A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B"],
           "Input":[0.1,0.15,0.08,0.11,0.2,0.15,0.1,0.04,0.11,0.2],
           "Output":[0.1,0.6,0.08,0.22,0.01,0.08,0.22,0.02,0.13,0.004]}

DB = pd.DataFrame(Test_Data)
DB.loc[:,"Ratio"] = DB["Output"]/DB["Input"]

DB:
    Sample Batch  Input  Output     Ratio
0  Control     A   0.10   0.100  1.000000
1    Test1     A   0.15   0.600  4.000000
2    Test2     A   0.08   0.080  1.000000
3    Test3     A   0.11   0.220  2.000000
4    Test4     A   0.20   0.010  0.050000
5  Control     B   0.15   0.080  0.533333
6    Test1     B   0.10   0.220  2.200000
7    Test2     B   0.04   0.020  0.500000
8    Test3     B   0.11   0.130  1.181818
9    Test4     B   0.20   0.004  0.020000
```

My desired output would be to normalize each ratio per Batch based on the Control sample, effectively multiplying all the Batch "B" samples by 1.875.

```
DB:
    Sample Batch  Input  Output     Ratio  Norm_Ratio
0  Control     A   0.10   0.100  1.000000    1.000000
1    Test1     A   0.15   0.600  4.000000    4.000000
2    Test2     A   0.08   0.080  1.000000    1.000000
3    Test3     A   0.11   0.220  2.000000    2.000000
4    Test4     A   0.20   0.010  0.050000    0.050000
5  Control     B   0.15   0.080  0.533333    1.000000
6    Test1     B   0.10   0.220  2.200000    4.125000
7    Test2     B   0.04   0.020  0.500000    0.937500
8    Test3     B   0.11   0.130  1.181818    2.215909
9    Test4     B   0.20   0.004  0.020000    0.037500
```

I can do this by breaking up the dataframe using for loops and manually extracting the "Control" values, but this is slow and messy for large datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
DB['Norm_Ratio'] = DB['Ratio'].div(
                    DB['Ratio'].where(DB['Sample'].eq('Control'))
                     .groupby(DB['Batch']).transform('first')
                    )
```

Output:

```
    Sample Batch  Input  Output     Ratio  Norm_Ratio
0  Control     A   0.10   0.100  1.000000    1.000000
1    Test1     A   0.15   0.600  4.000000    4.000000
2    Test2     A   0.08   0.080  1.000000    1.000000
3    Test3     A   0.11   0.220  2.000000    2.000000
4    Test4     A   0.20   0.010  0.050000    0.050000
5  Control     B   0.15   0.080  0.533333    1.000000
6    Test1     B   0.10   0.220  2.200000    4.125000
7    Test2     B   0.04   0.020  0.500000    0.937500
8    Test3     B   0.11   0.130  1.181818    2.215909
9    Test4     B   0.20   0.004  0.020000    0.037500
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  This works nicely.  I can follow the logic of the code right up until the `.groupby(DB['Batch']).transform('first')`.  Groupby would normally be used to collapse all the A's and B's into a single entry right, does the .transform(first) stop that?  Would like to understand how to re-use this code more effectively for new applications.

Comment: `transform` doesn't aggregate the rows but puts the computed values in each if the group's rows